# Lesscss doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, less

I have this html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="1.less" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>


    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="t1">t1</div>
    <div id="t2">t2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the `1.less` :

```
.transition {
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.shadow {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
}

    .shadow:hover {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
    }


.radius {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

header {
    background-color: #e3ffe3;
}

#t1 {
    .shadow;
    .transition;
}

#t2 {
}
```

but the style doesn't work and I don't know why. I used inspect element tool of chrome and found this exception:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/Projects/Web/Less%20Learning/1.less. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

**I don't know what does it mean. I want to know how can I resolve my problem.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Use a Web Server

You need to actually run a webserver (wamp, nginx, apache), and make the get request to a URI on that server, rather than making the GET request to a file; e.g. change the line:

```
$.get("E:/Projects/Web/Less Learning/1.less",
```

to read something like:

```
$.get("http://localhost/Projects/Web/Less Learning/1.less",
```

...also create file names without spaces for better organisation, example:

```
$.get("http://localhost/Projects/Web/assets/css/1.less",
```

and the initial request page needs to be made over HTTP as well.

You may also have to set `allow_url_include = On` in the server configuration in php.ini - not usually the case with nginx etc.

## 2. Cleaner folders

Instead of `Projects / Web  / Less Learning`

Try, `Projects / Web / Less`

And inside that:

```
 /projects/web/less/assets/css/less.less
 /projects/web/less/assets/css/css.css
 /projects/web/less/assets/js/less-1.3.0.min.js
 /projects/web/less/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If this .net platform web application you can use http://www.dotlesscss.org/.